# How to use the Jenkins docker plugin for containers that persist between stages

Tags: docker, jenkins

Below is an except from a Jenkins build pipeline script which will spin up a container and allow a number of actions to be performed from inside that container. My question is this, what does the syntax look like for using the docker plugin to create a container in one build stage which will still be up so that it can be used in subsequent build stages.

```
    docker.image('groovy:2.4').inside {
        sh 'groovy -v'
        // if you have a file called test.groovy in your jenkins workspace, you can "magically" access it
        // inside the container
        sh 'groovy test.groovy'
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inside` command causes the container to exit when the body finishes. To keep the container running use the following syntax:

```
docker.image('image-name').run {
   ...
}
```

This will keep the container running for later stages.

Comment: docker run -e \"ACCEPT_EULA=Y\" -e \"SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1\" --name SQLLinux${env.BRANCH_NAME} -d -i -p ${BranchToPort(env.BRANCH_NAME)}:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux"

Where do all the flags and parametrers this uses go when using the docker.image().run syntax ?

Comment: Do these all go inside the () after docker.image ?